# Failed to connect to port when trying to use SSH remote forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

I am learning how to do SSH remote forwarding and I am trying to practice that using two virtual machines on my computer. One is runs Kali and hosts an apache web server configured to listen on port 8000 and the other runs Manjaro and should act as the remote device. (I have set the network adapters to "Bridged mode" in VB). When I run the command:

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:8000 manjaro@192.168.3.126
```

It returns the following output:

```
manjaro@192.168.3.126's password: 
Last login: Sat Jul 30 16:09:45 2022 from 192.168.3.120
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ connect_to localhost port 8000: failed.
connect_to localhost port 8000: failed.
connect_to localhost port 8000: failed.
connect_to localhost port 8000: failed.
```

It prints out the "failed to connect" line every time I insert: `http://localhost:8080/`
into the web browser on the Manjaro VM
What can the problem be?

Comment: What does this have to SSH’ing into a machine this sounds like an Apache configuration issue. Without configuration files we cannot help you.

Comment: can you confirm the webserver is configured correctly by running `curl localhost:8000` on the server?

Comment: I'm confused about which part of this is happening on which machine. Which system are you `ssh`ing *from* (192.168.3.120?), and which one are you `ssh`ing into (192.168.3.126)?

Comment: I think that the server is configured correctly; the output of ```curl localhost:8080``` is this:https://pastebin.com/ypA2cbNZ

Comment: You had been asked to test `curl localhost:8000` but you tested `curl localhost:8080`. Didn't the discrepancy make you wonder? See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If (per your comment) `curl localhost:8080` works on Kali, then you need `-R …:localhost:8080` in your `ssh` command. In the command you used there is `-R …:localhost:8000`. The port is wrong.

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:8080 manjaro@192.168.3.126
#
#                           The machine with SSH server will listen
#      ^^^^                 on this port.
#
#                           The machine with SSH client will resolve
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  this address:port and it will forward
#                           connections to it.
```